# Magento: 2 Broken image in wysiwyg after overriding the file

Tags: custom-attributes, wysiwyg, customer-grid

I have override the file

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Indexer/Source.php
```

in this path

```
Magenticians\Moduleproduct\Model\Indexer\Source.php
```

just adding one function

```
public function addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias = null)
{
    $this->customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect($fieldName, $alias);
    return $this;
}
```

for re-indexing the customers which have custom attribute like account type.

every thing is fine, custom attribute account added , but in admin site  in WYSIWYG when I insert the image. a broken image is display. when I remove the overrides module every thing is fine. not image broken.

I want to identify the error. where is defect which create broken image?

Comment: here is module which i override for customer grid reindexing :

https://github.com/hafizjee/fix-customer-grid